# How to achieve using TRIM command on SELECT * From TABLE

Tags: oracle

I am building DWH where in source data dump is made through `SELECT *` query into DB. I am taking dump from the source DB, to save time (else had to write 115 select stmt using `TRIM` where average number of filed per table is 150) I used `SELECT * FROM TABLE` query to get the dump post which I am executing SED command to remove spaces from the fields.

This is taking a huge time & space as first `SELECT` query dumps the table and `sed` trims the Spaces. I have written a BJ to download the files & conversion.

There is space constraint in my server and I cannot mount extra space.

I am looking forward for inputs/tools/package/procedure on how can still use `SELECT *` but there are no spaces in the fields and I can avoid using `sed` command in UNIX.

Comment: Did I understand correctly that you need this because you don't want to type out the columns names? How about writing a program that generates the column list for you using the table meta data?

Comment: Hi Mikael, Yes you got it correct. Even post pulling out column list , I will have to add TRIM and then replace * with the complete list of columns. Any reusable component you have?

Comment: I could probably put something together if this is for SQL Server?

Comment: Would be kind of you, but I am using Oracle

Comment: SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'TABLE'.......can you plz elaborate on this query further, incorporating TRIM

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, this PL/SQL will do the job for you:

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR c1 IS SELECT table_name FROM USER_TABLES;
   QUERY varchar(4000);
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN c1 LOOP
    SELECT 'SELECT '||RTRIM(EXTRACT(COLXML,'//COLUMN_NAME/text()'),',')||' FROM '||rec.table_name||';' COL_STRING INTO QUERY
    FROM (SELECT E.table_name,
      xmlelement("USER_TAB_COLUMNS",
      XMLAGG(xmlelement("COLUMN_NAME", case when data_type like '%CHAR%' then 'TRIM(' end ||
      column_name||
      case when data_type like '%CHAR%' then '),' else ',' end) 
    ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME)) COLXML
    FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS E WHERE TABLE_NAME=rec.table_name
    GROUP BY E.table_name );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(QUERY);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Make sure you `set serveroutput on` to get the output from `DBMS_OUTPUT`.

Change the query in the `CURSOR` to alter the table list it generates queries for.

Note: Doesn't do anything for 'CLOB'/'BLOB' columns.

Example output:

```
SELECT A,TRIM(B),TRIM(C) FROM BLAH;
SELECT A,B FROM EDITIONTEST;
SELECT C,D FROM EDITIONTEST2;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Another thing to mention; You're going to be limited to the 4000 character limit, but will be OK unless you have tables with hundreds of columns.